# How to scroll page in Pdf Component of react-native-pdf

Tags: react-native

I am developing a page that includes showing pdf files by react-native on android.
I want to scroll in Pdf component but it can not scroll? How to fix it?
My code is:

```
<ScrollView
    style="{styles.container}"
    stickyHeaderIndices="{[0]}"
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator="{true}"
    nestedScrollEnabled="{true}"
>
    // <header />
    {/*Other component*/}
    <View style="{styles.inner}">
        <View style="{styles.pdfContainer}">
            {/*Other component*/}
            <View style="{styles.pdfBody}">
                <Pdf source={source} trustAllCerts={true}
                onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
                console.log(`Number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`); }}
                onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => { console.log(`Current
                page: ${page}`); }} onError={(error) => { console.log(error); }}
                onPressLink={(uri) => { console.log(`Link pressed: ${uri}`); }}
                style={styles.pdf} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

I do try to solve by using ScrollView wrapping Pdf or using nestedScrollEnabled={true}
I don't know to solve it!

Comment: You may follow the code example provided by `react-native-pdf` [docs](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf). Actually you do not need an external ScrollView to do that, PDF will be scrollable when the PDF document is more that 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you put your pdf component in a scroll view and use this code as a wrapper.

```
    const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(true);
    
    <ScrollView scrollEnabled={scroll}>
      ... other components
     <ScrollView 
      nestedScrollEnabled={true}
      onTouchStart={ => setScroll(false)}
      onTouchEnd={ => setScroll(true)}
      onTouchCancel={ => setScroll(true)}
     >
     <Pdf source={source} trustAllCerts={true}
                    onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => { }}
                    onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {}} 
                    onError={ }}
                    onPressLink={(uri) => { }}
                    style={styles.pdf} />`enter code here`
     </ScrollView>
     ... other components 
    </ScrollView>
```